# How to load classes from jar file in correct order

Tags: java, classloader, java-bytecode-asm

I have written a Java Classloader to load classes from a jar file.

```
Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry element = entries.nextElement();
        if (element.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
               //Class Manipulation via ASM
               //Loading class with MyClassloader
        }
    }
```

The Problem is:
When I load a Class, which Sublcass from a Class in the same Jar and the subclass isn't already loaded, I get a ClassNotFoundException.

Example:

```
class A extends B{}
Class B{}
```

Because of the alphabetical order, Class A is loaded first. I Get a ClassNotFoundException for Class B. At this time, Class B isn't loaded.

Comment: Show the code you commented out, which is where the actual issue is. (Unless, of course, your class `B` is misnamed or otherwise not included in the search classpath.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that your class loading is performed as some sort of *pushing* class files. You should however rather *pull* them. To explain what I mean by this, let us look at a short example of normal Java class loading:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new B();
  }
}
class B extends A { }
class A { }
```

When creating a `new B()`, the class loader of `Main` basically executes `classLoader.loadClass("B")`. At this point, `B`'s super class `A` is not yet loaded. At the same time, the class loader cannot know that `B` has `A` as its super class. Thus, the class loader takes responsibility for loading the class by asking itself to `classLoader.loadClass("A")` before the class loading of `B` is completed.

Let us assume that the class loader did not know about either `A` or `B` but it had a method to explicitly load classes it is receives by an external entity with `classLoader.inject(String, byte[])`. This calling sequence would then not compute:

```
classLoader.inject("B", bBytes);
classLoader.inject("A", aBytes);
```

because while loading `B`, the class loader would not yet know about `A`.

What you need to do when implementing your own class loader is to store the classes in some sort of map and to implement the class loader's class loading method something like:

```
protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
  byte[] bytes = map.get(name);
  if (bytes != null) {
    return defineClass(name, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
  } else {
    throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
  }
}
```

By allowing the class loader to determine the loading order, you avoid this problem altogether.

To be even more precise, you need to do manipulation and loading in two steps where a pseudo algorithm would look something like this:

```
Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();
MyClassLoader classLoader = new MyClassLoader();
// First we generate ALL classes that the class loader is supposed to load.
// We then make these classes accessible to the class loader.
while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
  JarEntry element = entries.nextElement();
  if (element.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
     // Class Manipulation via ASM
     classLoader.addClass( ... );
  }
}
// Now that the class loader knows about all classes that are to be loaded
// we trigger the loading process. That way, the class loader can query
// itself about ANY class that it should know.
while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
  JarEntry element = entries.nextElement();
  if (element.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
     classLoader.loadClass( ... );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's how you would implement it internally. You would however never expose define class to the outside.

Comment: Sorry I deleted the comment before. My problem is, I don't get the part where the classloader determinates, that class B has to be loaded before class A if class A extends B{}.

Comment: It is a VM intrinsic. If a class loader realizes, it needs to load another class before loading the current class, it pauses the current class loading and **queries itself** for the next class. This is why all relevant classes must be know from within the class loader before loading the first class. Set a break point within the load class method and you will understand what is going on.

Comment: @user3676760: you are under the misconception that this was an ordering problem, however, Java classes may have circular dependencies, so it isn’t an ordering issue and can’t be generally solved by defining classes in a specific order. The important point is that your `ClassLoader` has to provide the `Class` when the JVM asks for it. At that time the resolving of the class’ dependencies might be incomplete but the JVM will remember that and proceed with resolving afterwards thus being able to resolve even circular dependencies (it will ask your `ClassLoader` at most once for a specific class).